# Preenchimento de campos com CEP em CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, ajax, json, cakephp-2, cep

Estou tentando fazer o preenchimento automático dos campos em CakePHP a partir de um CEP, estou adaptando o código encontrado nesse site:

http://matheuspiscioneri.com.br/blog/preenchimento-automatico-do-endereco-a-partir-do-cep/

Utilizei como exemplo o seguinte site, para saber como configurar requisições ajax para o Framework:

http://blog.erikfigueiredo.com.br/requisicoes-ajax-com-cakephp-artigo-super-completo/

Aqui encontra-se meu código:

## ContatosController

```
class ContatoController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public $uses = array();

    public function beforeRender()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->layout = "ajax";
        }   
    }

    public function consulta_cep() {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $reg = simplexml_load_file("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep=" . $cep);

            $dados = $reg->sucesso($this->request->data['resultado']);
            $dados = $reg->rua($this->request->data['tipo_logradouro' . ' ' . 'logradouro']);
            $dados = $reg->bairro($this->request->data['bairro']);
            $dados = $reg->cidade($this->request->data['cidade']);
            $dados = $reg->estado($this->request->data['uf']);

            echo json_encode($dados);
        }
    }
```

## teste.ctp

```
base_url = 
$(document).ready( function() {
    /* Executa a requisição quando o campo CEP perder o foco */
    $('#cep').blur(function(){
       /* Configura a requisição AJAX */
       $.ajax({
            url : 'consulta_cep()', /* URL que será chamada */ 
            type : 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */ 
            data: 'cep=' + $('#cep').val(), /* dado que será enviado via POST */
            dataType: 'json', /* Tipo de transmissão */
            success: function(data){
                if(data.sucesso == 1){
                    $('#rua').val(data.rua);
                    $('#bairro').val(data.bairro);
                    $('#cidade').val(data.cidade);
                    $('#estado').val(data.estado);

                    $('#numero').focus();
                }
            }
       });   
    return false;    
    })
});

<fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('Contato');
    ?>
    <? php
        echo $this->Form->input('cep');
        echo $this->Form->input('rua');
        echo $this->Form->input('numero');
        echo $this->Form->input('bairro');
        echo $this->Form->input('cidade');
        echo $this->Form->input('estado');
    ?>
</fieldset>
```

## routes.php

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Estou com algumas dúvidas:

1. Na url da **view teste.ctp** o que devo colocar, pois quero chamar a função **consulta_cep** que se encontra na **ContatoController**
2. A forma como estou fazendo no controller para jogar os dados que retornam na variável $reg para a variável $dados está correta, pois no site que utilizei como exemplo ele está convertendo para String antes de atribuir os valores a variável $dados?

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês, porque não encontrei nenhum exemplo na internet para o CakePHP que utilize preencha os dados a partir do CEP e estou tentando ajudar a comunidade com o conhecimento que tenho no Framework, para que possam utilizar de uma funcionalidade básica, mas que ajuda e muito os desenvolvedores em seus projetos.

Obrigado

Comment: Particularmente eu não sou muito fã de u8sar as requisições ajax do cake, normalmente eu construo as minhas próprias com jQuery mesmo. Apesar de usar o Cake na maioria dos projetos que eu trabalho, lidar com javascript é umas das coisas que eu não gosto de fazer pelo cake, até pelo fato de ser muito mais chato usar o *grunt* dessa forma. Meu conselho é fazer a requisição ajax e a manipulação em um JS mesmo.

Comment: Concordo, Erlon. Mas já não é isso que ele está fazendo?

Comment: @bfavaretto, sim em parte, no caso a intenção era dizer que ele não precisa nem criar um método no cake para parsear o `XML`. Basta ele parsear o `XML` no js.

Comment: @ErlonCharles poderia me dar um exemplo de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Usando o parseXML do jQuery @RafaelMangueira http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/